# Execute SQL statements while looping a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table with a few records in it and then run a set of sql statements for every record in that table. I would use the data in the table to set values in the sql statement.

This should allow me to write the SQL just once and then run it for whatever data I put in the table.

But, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Should I use a cursor to loop the table?  Some other way?

Thanks for any help or advice you can give me.

Comment: Yes, a `CURSOR` would work. But whether that's the best solution depends on what exactly you'll try to do inside the loop (you may not need it).

Comment: What database? This sounds more like a job for stored procedures.

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm going to put several INSERT statements to populate a series of tables.

Comment: @Tawnos Yes, all of this would live inside a stored procedure. I'm trying to avoid making 10 calls to a stored procedure and passing in 15 values.  Unless that's just the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURSOR will have an overhead associated with it, but can be a good method to walk through your table.  They are not a totally unnecessary evil and have their place.

With the limited information that WilliamB2 provided, it sounds like a CURSOR set may be a good solution for this problem to walk through his data and generate the multiple downstream INSERTs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a cursor. You can also use a while loop

```
declare @table as table(col1 int, col2 varchar(20))

declare @col1 int
declare @col2 varchar(50)

declare @sql varchar(max)

insert into @table
SELECT col1, col2 FROM OriginalTable

while(exists(select top 1 'x' from @table)) --as long as @table contains records continue
begin
   select top 1 @col1=col1, @col2=col2 from @table

   SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO Table t VALUES('+cast(@col1 as varchar)+')'


   delete top (1) from @table --remove the previously processed row. also ensures no infinite loop
end
```

I think cursor has an overhead attached to it.

With this second approach you are not working on the original table

Comment: Note that at the 'SET @sql =' line, you would need to execute those statements against your database, or collect them in some way for later execution.

Also note that you are duplicating in memory your OriginalTable which will incur some memory overhead.

Comment: Yes that's true. But the table won't be locked by CURSOR while looping.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `INSERT...SELECT` instead of the loop:

```
INSERT INTO target_table
SELECT
    some_col,
    some_other_col,
    'Some fixed value',
    NULL,
    42,
    you_get_the_idea
FROM source_table
WHERE source_table.you_get_the_idea = 1
```

The columns on your `SELECT` should match the structure of the target table (you can omit an int/identity pk like `id` if you have one).

If the best option is this or the loop depends on how many tables you want to populate inside the loop. If it's just a few, I usually stick with `INSERT...SELECT`.

Comment: I'm not actually inserting data from my source table into my target table. I'm using the fields in my source table to set parameters in my INSERT statements to populate other tables.  For instance, if my source table was all the information I had about different types of fruit, and I was using that to then insert a bunch of statistics about fruits into another table.